# How to make the .data() call for this data format?

Tags: d3.js

I now have data in an array as

```
A=[{“id”=3, “s1”=0.3, “s2”=0.5},{“id”=6, “s1”=0.3, “s2”=0.5},{“id”=23, “s1”=0.3, “s2”=0.5},….] etc
```

and I add it by:

```
.data(A, function(d) {return d.id})
```

Which works as intended.

Now I’d like to have a different data structure more like:

```
B={“3”:{“s1":0.3,"s2":0.5},"6":{"s1":0.3,"s2”:0.5},”23”:{“s1":0.3,"s2":0.5}}
```

But I am not sure how to make the .data() call for this structure, I.e. how to write the function providing the indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 `data()` method accepts only 3 things:

- An array
- A function
- Nothing

Therefore, you cannot use that object (`B`) you have. You need to convert it in an array.

For instance, here is a solution (out of many) for converting it into an array similar to your first one (`A`):

```js
const B = {
  "3": {
    "s1": 0.3,
    "s2": 0.5
  },
  "6": {
    "s1": 0.3,
    "s2": 0.5
  },
  "23": {
    "s1": 0.3,
    "s2": 0.5
  }
};

const data = Object.keys(B).map(function(d) {
  return Object.assign({}, B[d], {
    id: d
  })
});

console.log(data)
```

The difference here is that `id` is a string, not a number. If you want a number instead, just coerce it.

Comment: Ok, this answered my question, i.e. I cannot use the associative array for the .data() call in d3. it has to be an "ordinary" array with square brackets. Thanks!

Comment: As I digged a bit deeper there is also built in functionality:

    d3.entries(B)

Comment: Nope, it's not the same, `d3.entries()` will give you a very different array.